# ggplot aes issue: Error: is.integer(group) is not TRUE

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have noticed several other similar questions (two recently, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397212/error-while-using-ggplot2)) on this issue which unfortunately were not addressed (or thought to have been old issues).

I have been using v 3.3.1 (32-bit), but have recently upgraded to v3.3.3 (Another Canoe), 64-bit. I am using Rstudio 1.0.136 on Windows 7 64 bit.

Since upgrading to v3.3.3 `ggplot` no longer works (it worked with 3.3.1) with the above error message "Error: is.integer(group) is not TRUE" occurring when passing aesthetics through to any `ggplot` function calls. I get the error with any call to any `ggplot` functions including all example function calls in the `ggplot` vignettes, on the `ggplot` examples, and tuition sites. So it is not specific to my code.

For example, here is a line of code that gives the error:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
```

Therefore it would appear to be linked to a package version bug, missing update, or incompatibility with R v3.3.3. Other advice has suggested updating all packages. Several other people have said updating doesn't work; I can confirm that this did not fix the issue for me either. It's not clear exactly which packages need to be updated, but as far as I know I have all required updates for `ggplot`. I have tried updating from multiple cran mirrors.

EDIT: As requested here is the sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:

[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

[1] colorspace_1.2-4 scales_0.4.1 lazyeval_0.2.0 plyr_1.8 tools_3.3.3 gtable_0.1.2    

[7] tibble_1.3.3 Rcpp_0.12.9  grid_3.3.3   rlang_0.1.1  munsell_0.4.2
```

As I said it relates to passing aes objects through to gg functions. The functions run without an aes but obviously don't produce much and it is possible to construct aes objects so its not an obvious constructor issue.

EDIT. I have ruled out RStudio as I have done all recent testing from the R command line. Other possibilities include package update problems. The machine is a bit locked down but usually I have no problems installing and updating packages.

I may report it to the package maintainers but am hoping someone may actually have a fix without regarding it as a bug report yet and I have confirmed that all the versions work with 3.3.3 on a different machine.

Comment: Just to be clear; you encounter `Error: is.integer(group) is not TRUE` when loading the `ggplot2` package then evaluating that `ggplot()` command in a clean session? Could you please link the two similar questions also?

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Yes I have checked with a completely clean session and just loading ggplot2 and running the mtcars line. Will try to work out how to link :)

Comment: This is the main one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397212/error-while-using-ggplot2

Comment: More to the point I guess, a fixed value of `colour` in `aes()` probably isn't what you want - that should either be outside of the `aes()` call or be a variable.

Comment: Thats irrelevant. I will edit it out. It doesnt work with anything. I just copied that but as I said it works with nothing

Comment: It's hard for someone who doesn't reproduce the bug to see what's irrelevant or not.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't update to `3.4.1` (current stable)?

Comment: I dont have permissions to upgrade. I appreciate your help but don't patronise me please. There is a tendency on here for people to patronise people reporting bugs and not taking it seriously. As someone with 40+ years programming experience it doesn't go down well.

Comment: I'm not sure what's patronising about my response but rest assured I'm done trying to help. Best of luck, have a great day.

Comment: No worries Jonathan. Thanks for your help. Hopefully someone will post a solution so other people don't have the same issue. As I said, people come here looking for solutions and get dismissed. All the best. My suspicion is that one of the libraries isn't handling 64/32 bit integers properly. WHo voted it down. Thats typical of people's attitude here

Comment: FWIW, your comments at the top of the question will almost certainly attract more down votes and negative attention, and will probably discourage many knowledgeable people from trying to help. That may or may not be _fair_, I'm just advising you as to what the likely outcome will be.

Comment: Thats cool joran. I'm not really the one needing help. I am sharing my expertise and hoping someone will take the issue seriously so others benefit. I also find the way two people downvoted such an important issue rather childish especially considering I had spent 2-3 hours testing and researching every possible angle of the problem. ATM the only work around seems to be not to use 64 bit 3.3.3 on Windows. Cheers

Comment: If your goal is to help others with the same issue, please link to the relevant bug report or offsite continuation of this issue.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. PS That is of course restricted to the machine I have been testing on and other people with the same problem and of course I am not an admin so am limited testing this machine :)

Comment: There's something other than R and package version here. I'm running R-3.3.3 (64bit) with `ggplot2-2.2.1`, and your 1-liner above does not produce an error. (Win10, if it matters.)

Comment: It would be helpful to give complete `sessionInfo()` results for both the working (3.3.1) and (3.3.3) configurations; this would indicate your OS (both platform and 32/64-bit), which could be helpful in narrowing down the problem. (Would also be helpful to run in the cleanest session possible to avoid having to check too many package versions: for example, I doubt `tibble` must be attached to use ggplot?)

Comment: just a guess, but can you update `plyr`?  That was a problem in some similar (but very much older) cases.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the further comments. I apologise to everyone, especially Jonathan,  if my language was taken wrongly and came across as aggressive. It wasn't meant against Jonathan in that way and was more a sense of frustration having spent hours of time I didn't have trying to fix the issue, researching the issue, finding several unsolved posts etc. I know how it feels trying to explain testing to people and its just that I'd already been through so many of the steps before posting.

Comment: And as I said, unfortunately I have limited control over the machine in order to try fixing it. I will check again tomorrow as I am using my own machine today on which R3.3.3 64 bit Windows 10 and Rstudio 0.99 and ggplot all work fine. I will try plyr update again but I updated all libraries. Could the R-studio update have done anything. I wouldn't have thought it wouldn't interact with the R-session in that way but who knows - without being able to find the source of the error message in the code. Will respond tomorrow.  regards all

Comment: Apologies. tried posting a session info here. Please ignore.

Comment: I've ruled Rstudio out as I'm testing now from command line. There are a few revision number discrepanices between working 3.3.1 (32 bit)  and not working 3.3.3 (64 bit). Plyr (working) is 1.8.4 and plyr (not working) is 1.8. The update packages from several mirrors did not update any versions. Any chance there is a package update problem in R settings. As I said I had no control over install. More later as I will try to find a solution but am sticking with working version for now.

Comment: Thanks for the positive comments, Duncan. I don't use R, but this strikes me as a niche issue. If you could use a bounty on it (to get more attention from the R community here) let me know, and I will add one.

Comment: OK This is frustrating. As suspected it was a package update issue and it was plyr when I was able to get 1.8.4 installed. The unanswered issue is is:  I did not actually update plyr from 1.8 to 1.8.4 since last week. What I did was reinstall ggplot (yet again ) from CRAN. Somewhere between versions of R on mirrors, different package libraries on my locked down machine and between a Thursday and a Monday update ggplot now works. One of those fun problems. But as others said above it was plyr and as I originally suspected it was down to package update problems somewhere. The question is where?

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I see exactly the same error; using Ubuntu 14.04; R3.3.3 Another Canoe

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))

produces error:   Error: is.integer(group) is not TRUE

### I updated package plyr, and that resolved this issue;